# Questions about epoll and the data struct

Tags: c, epoll

Will the fd returned in the epoll event event.data.fd, always remain the same fd descriptor between each time using epoll_wait() and can it be used to identify that connection each time and the state associated with it.

Comment: If you're polling multiple FDs, `event.data.fd` can be any of them. It will be whichever have become ready.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand the basics of how `epoll` works. Of course the FD identifies the connection, it's the same FD that you use to send/receive.

Comment: There's an example showing how it's used at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

Comment: But can the exact value of the fd change if epoll for example dup2's that fd to a different one? Is it possible for the value of the fd corresponding to a specific connection to change with epoll?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what happens, but a number of web pages warn against using dup'ed descriptors with `epoll`, because the polling is associated with the underlying file description. But the FAQ in the man page suggests this can also be useful if you have different poll masks on each FD.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains this quite clearly:

> The  data  field of each returned structure contains the same data as was specified in the most recent call to `epoll_ctl`(2) (`EPOLL_CTL_ADD`, `EPOLL_CTL_MOD`) for the corresponding open file description.

So the returned value of `event.data.fd` will be whatever value you specified for `event.data.fd` in the last call to `epoll_ctl` for that open file description. Unless you're messing with `fork` or `dup`, and using `epoll` on both descriptors, that will be the last call to `epoll_ctl` for that file descriptor.